# Server doesn't send SYN+ACK

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I have a client and a server. They work fine when running on the same machine, but when I try connecting a client from outside my network then my server won't send the `SYN+ACK` packet in response to a `SYN` packet.

Using Wireshark I can see the `SYN` packet coming from the client, but I don't see the `SYN+ACK` packet going out to the client.

I've found some solutions that say to turn off TCP window scaling and TCP timestamps but that didn't work for me. Also, with the `netstat -ln` command on the server side, I can see

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Here is the Wireshark output on the server side:

[image: Server side wireshark print]

Here are my IP tables:

[image: IPTables]

Comment: Check your firewall configuration. Wireshark might capture the traffic before it enters the firewall so that you see the SYN in Wireshark but your application never gets it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I used "sudo ufw allow myport" and if I use "sudo ufw status" it says ALLOW, for my port. I guess it's done, right? but still no result

Comment: Given that netstat shows the listening socket and that the TCP handshake is done in the kernel (i.e. no application malfunction) my guess is still that there is either the firewall or that you've interpreted the wireshark output the wrong way. One might have a closer look  if you add *all* the iptables rules and the wireshark/tcpdump output to your question.

Comment: Where are you running Wireshark? In the client or in the server node?

Comment: @PedroMaltez Then there is still a firewall issue. Figure out how to completely stop and disable the firewall you have on your system so you can verify this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've edited the post. Don't know if you are notified or need to mention you so..

Comment: @rodolk I already run it in both. In client side i can see the SYN packets going out. In server side I see the SYN packets coming in but there are no SYN+ACK packets going out in response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three possibilities you must evaluate:

1. There is an iptables rule in the server that is dropping the SYN before sending to TCP stack
2. There is an iptables rule in the server that is dropping the SYN-ACK before sending out
3. There is a wrong route that is sending the SYN-ACK through some other interface (I doubt this is the case because I'd expect to use the same interface through which the SYN was received)

Comment: It's solved. I was connected with the client through vpn and it may have caused the problem. I changed the ip to the one of tap0 interface and it worked.

Comment: @rodolk, i disabled firewalld, iptables, ufw,.. all of those firewall stuff. And tried to disable tcp_timestamps, tcp_tw_recycle, tcp_window_scaling; plus increasing net.core.somaxconn using sysctl. Still the syn+ack packet not sent to client

Comment: @datdinhquoc Is the server receiving any SYN at all?

Comment: @rodolk, yes, client stuck at SYN_SENT, and server stuck at SYN_RECV